# Are two outputs of a quantum operation (CPTP map) themselves related by a quantum operation?

Tags: quantum-operation

$\def\ket#1{|#1\rangle}
\def\bra#1{\langle#1|}
\def\mt#1{\mathrm{#1}}
\def\E{\mathcal E}
\def\F{\mathcal F}$
Let $\ket\phi$ and $\ket\psi$ be pure states on the same quantum system, so that $\ket\psi=\mt U\ket\phi$ for some unitary $\mt U$.
Say we have a quantum operation (CPTP map) $\E$, and write $\sigma_\phi=\E(\ket\phi\bra\phi)$, $\sigma_\psi=\E(\ket\psi\bra\psi)$.

**Question**: given that $\ket\psi$ and $\ket\phi$ are related by a unitary $\mt U$, are $\sigma_\psi$ and $\sigma_\phi$ related by a quantum operation? I.e. does there exist a quantum operation $\F$ such that $\sigma_\psi=\F(\sigma_\phi)$ (or the other way around)?

My feeling says this has to be true, but I'm struggling to prove it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two states are *always* related by a CPTP map, regardless where they come from.

Just take e.g. $$\mathcal F(\rho) =\mathrm{tr}(\rho) \, \sigma_\psi\ . $$

Comment: Ah right, this indeed works. Thanks!

Comment: Blatant self-advertisement: [Canonical examples of quantum channels](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/291810/canonical-examples-of-quantum-channels/291811#291811), #5  ;)